# How avoid \" in json's string?

Tags: spring-boot, gson, activemq-classic

Spring boot app

In build.gradle:

```
implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.7'
```

Here JMSConfiguration:

```
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jms.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.jms.config.DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.config.JmsListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MappingJackson2MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageConverter;
import org.springframework.jms.support.converter.MessageType;
@Configuration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "ru.otus.software_architect.eshop")
public class JMSConfiguration {

    @Bean
    public JmsListenerContainerFactory<?> myFactory(ConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
                                                    DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactoryConfigurer configurer) {
        DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory factory = new DefaultJmsListenerContainerFactory();
        // This provides all boot's default to this factory, including the message converter
        configurer.configure(factory, connectionFactory);
        // You could still override some of Boot's default if necessary.
        return factory;
    }

    @Bean
    public MessageConverter jacksonJmsMessageConverter() {
        MappingJackson2MessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2MessageConverter();
        converter.setTargetType(MessageType.TEXT);
        converter.setTypeIdPropertyName("_type");
        return converter;
    }
}
```

Here how I send message to ActiviveMQ:

```
private void sendMessageToMessageBroker(NotifyActionEnum action, int orderId) {
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("email", UserService.getCurrentUserName());
        json.addProperty("action", action.name().toLowerCase());
        json.addProperty("orderId", orderId);
        JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
        String message = json.toString();
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(ESHOP_QUEUE, message);
        logger.info("sendMessageToMessageBroker: success_sent_message_to_MB: " + message);
    }
```

Here in log:

`success_sent_message_to_MB`:

```
{"email":"someemail@email.com","action":"order_update","orderId":14}
```

Nice.

But on ActiveMQ in the my queue the message look like this:

```
  "{\"email\":\"a_subscriber@mail.ru\",\"action\":\"order_update\",\"orderId\":4,\"createdAt\":\"2020-09-13T11:32:09.976+0300\"}"
```

Here screenshot:

[image]

And I start my another application (consumer). And it's broken when try to get date from json:

```
JsonElement messageJson = GsonUtil.parser.parse(message);
String action = messageJson.getAsJsonObject().get("action").getAsString(); // here broken
```

I get error message:

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not a JSON Object: "{\"email\":\"a_subscriber@mail.ru\",\"action\":\"order_update\",\"orderId\":4,\"createdAt\":\"2020-09-13T11:32:09.976+0300\"}"
```

How I can avoid \" in string?

I need to queue to be the next string:

```
{"email":"someemail@email.com","action":"order_update","orderId":14}
```

Comment: Something is putting the string in double quotes, and needs to escape the double quotes in the string for this to work.

Comment: @Steve Why in queue show string with \" ?

Comment: My guess is because of the quotes at the beginning and end of the string.  Whatever mechanism is adding those quotes is also escaping the quotes in the middle of the string by putting '\' in front of each of them.  Why this is happening, I do not know.

Comment: What `MessageConverter` do you have configured for your `JmsTemplate`? Are you using the default `SimpleMessageConverter` that converts a `String` into a `javax.jms.TextMessage`?

Comment: @JustinBertram I was updated my post

Comment: @JaredSmith I was added my solution

Answer (score 0):

Try using the default `MessageConverter` (i.e. [`SimpleMessageConverter`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/jms/support/converter/SimpleMessageConverter.html)) and sending your message as a `byte[]`, e.g.:

```java
private void sendMessageToMessageBroker(NotifyActionEnum action, int orderId) {
   JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
   json.addProperty("email", UserService.getCurrentUserName());
   json.addProperty("action", action.name().toLowerCase());
   json.addProperty("orderId", orderId);
   JmsTemplate jmsTemplate = context.getBean(JmsTemplate.class);
   String message = json.toString();
   jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(ESHOP_QUEUE, message.getBytes());
   logger.info("sendMessageToMessageBroker: success_sent_message_to_MB: " + message);
}
```

When you send the message as a `byte[]` the `SimpleMessageConverter` will convert it to a `javax.jms.BytesMessage`. When your consumer receives the message it can convert the `byte[]` to a `String` like so:

```java
String messageAsString;
if (message instanceof BytesMessage) {
   BytesMessage bytesMessage = (BytesMessage) message;
   byte[] buffer = new byte[(int) bytesMessage.getBodyLength()];
   bytesMessage.readBytes(buffer);   
   messageAsString = new String(buffer);
}
JsonElement messageJson = GsonUtil.parser.parse(messageAsString);
String action = messageJson.getAsJsonObject().get("action").getAsString();
```

I believe sending the message as a `byte[]` will avoid any unwanted escaping.

Comment: is it possible to understand what producer send via web console?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.

Comment: I want to see some informations like `{"email":"someemail@email.com","action":"order_update","orderId":14}` via ui tools

Comment: I'm not sure if the ActiveMQ web console will decode the `byte[]` into a `String` for display. Keep in mind that messages (even text messages) can be encoded in many different ways and the broker doesn't necessarily have the information it needs to decode the message into a human readable format (assuming such a format exists).

Comment: I believe that web console cannot decode from byte[] to string, cuz byte[] can be anything. but order_id may be a piece of very useful information which should able to see as human language

Comment: @JustinBertram In my consumer I change   @ JmsListener (destination = ESHOP_QUEUE)
    public void receiveMessage (BytesMessage message) {.. . but I get error:org.springframework.messaging.converter.MessageConversionException: Cannot convert from [java.lang.String] to [javax.jms.BytesMessage

Comment: @JustinBertram I was added my solution

Answer (score 0):

I use `urlEncode/decode` to send message to ActiveMQ

In my Controller:

```
private String publishToMessageBroker(NotifyActionEnum action, int orderId) {
        logger.info("publishToMessageBroker:");
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        json.addProperty("email", UserService.getCurrentUserName());
        json.addProperty("action", action.name().toLowerCase());
        json.addProperty("orderId", orderId);
        json.addProperty("createdAt", DateUtil.date2String(new Date(), DateUtil.JSON_DATE_FORMAT));
        String message = json.toString();
        String urlEncodeMessage = StringUtll.urlEncode(message);
        jmsTemplate.convertAndSend(ESHOP_QUEUE, urlEncodeMessage);
        logger.info("publishToMessageBroker: success_sent_message_to_MB: " + message);
        return "Message was success published on Message Broker!"; // can use as response
}
```

And now in ActiveMQ the message look like this:

```
"%7B%22email%22%3A%22myemail%40mail.com%22%2C%22action%22%3A%22order_delete%22%2C%22orderId%22%3A6%2C%22createdAt%22%3A%222020-09-19T12%3A20%3A57.844%2B0300%22%7D"
```

And now in message receiver I decode message

```
 @JmsListener(destination = ESHOP_QUEUE)
    public void receiveMessage(String urlEncodeMessage) {
        try {
            String urlDecodeMessage = StringUtil.urlDecode(urlEncodeMessage);
            String pureDecodeMessage = StringUtil.removeFirstAndLastQuotes(urlDecodeMessage);
            JsonElement messageJson = GsonUtil.parser.parse(pureDecodeMessage);
```

And now is work fine. No mor escape symbols like **""**.

After url decode I get pure json:

```
"{"email":"myemail@mail.com","action":"order_delete","orderId":6,"createdAt":"2020-09-19T12:20:57.844+0300"}"
```